# Filter/Subset one dataframe by the dates of a smaller one

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to filter a very large dataframe (>70k rows) by the contents of a significantly smaller (with some conditions attached to it).
A dput of the smaller one (df1, the one I want to use to filter the larger) is:

```
structure(list(Date = c("30/01/2023", "21/11/2022", "28/11/2022", 
"24/11/2022", "21/11/2022", "24/11/2022", "21/11/2022", "28/11/2022", 
"28/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "24/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "21/11/2022", 
"24/11/2022", "23/01/2023", "28/11/2022", "30/01/2023", "30/01/2023", 
"30/01/2023", "28/11/2022", "21/11/2022", "21/11/2022", "30/01/2023", 
"24/11/2022", "30/01/2023", "30/01/2023", "30/01/2023", "30/01/2023", 
"30/01/2023", "30/01/2023", "30/01/2023", "30/01/2023", "21/11/2022", 
"23/01/2023", "28/11/2022", "30/01/2023", "23/01/2023", "24/11/2022", 
"30/01/2023", "30/01/2023", "30/01/2023", "23/01/2023", "30/01/2023", 
"21/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "23/01/2023", "23/01/2023", 
"30/01/2023", "21/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "24/11/2022", 
"23/01/2023", "23/01/2023", "30/01/2023", "23/01/2023", "21/11/2022", 
"30/01/2023", "21/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "30/01/2023", "24/11/2022", 
"21/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "21/11/2022", "24/11/2022", "21/11/2022", 
"23/01/2023", "24/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "24/11/2022", "21/11/2022", 
"24/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "23/01/2023", "21/11/2022", "24/11/2022", 
"23/01/2023", "23/01/2023", "30/01/2023", "23/01/2023", "24/11/2022", 
"30/01/2023", "21/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "21/11/2022", "21/11/2022", 
"21/11/2022", "21/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "21/11/2022", "21/11/2022", 
"21/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "23/01/2023", "21/11/2022", 
"28/11/2022", "23/01/2023", "24/11/2022", "24/11/2022", "24/11/2022", 
"28/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "24/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "28/11/2022", 
"21/11/2022", "24/11/2022", "24/11/2022", "28/11/2022", "21/11/2022", 
"23/01/2023", "28/11/2022", "21/11/2022", "21/11/2022", "21/11/2022", 
"30/01/2023", "30/01/2023"), Height = c("Long", "Short", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Short", "Medium", "Short", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Medium", "Short", "Medium", "Short", "Medium", "Long", 
"Long", "Long", "Medium", "Short", "Short", "Long", "Medium", 
"Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", "Long", 
"Short", "Short", "Medium", "Long", "Short", "Medium", "Long", 
"Long", "Long", "Short", "Long", "Short", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Short", "Short", "Long", "Short", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Short", "Short", "Long", "Short", "Short", "Long", "Short", 
"Medium", "Long", "Medium", "Short", "Medium", "Short", "Medium", 
"Short", "Short", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Short", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Short", "Short", "Medium", "Short", "Short", "Long", 
"Short", "Medium", "Long", "Short", "Medium", "Short", "Short", 
"Short", "Short", "Medium", "Short", "Short", "Short", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Short", "Short", "Medium", "Short", "Medium", "Medium", 
"Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Short", 
"Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Short", "Short", "Medium", "Short", 
"Short", "Short", "Long", "Long"), Type = c("Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2")), row.names = c(4L, 
10L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 29L, 35L, 36L, 39L, 44L, 46L, 
51L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 59L, 64L, 72L, 73L, 76L, 78L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 
90L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 97L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 111L, 
114L, 115L, 116L, 118L, 120L, 122L, 124L, 128L, 137L, 143L, 144L, 
153L, 161L, 162L, 164L, 166L, 169L, 174L, 176L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 
192L, 194L, 197L, 198L, 202L, 203L, 205L, 207L, 209L, 211L, 215L, 
218L, 219L, 221L, 224L, 228L, 235L, 238L, 248L, 253L, 256L, 259L, 
274L, 284L, 285L, 287L, 298L, 302L, 310L, 311L, 316L, 320L, 326L, 
330L, 340L, 344L, 347L, 349L, 352L, 354L, 356L, 370L, 371L, 373L, 
375L, 376L, 377L, 380L, 382L, 387L, 392L, 398L, 400L, 403L, 404L, 
405L, 408L, 410L, 412L, 414L), class = "data.frame")
```

A snippet of the much larger one (df2) is:

```
data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(Date = structure(c(19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 19397, 
19397, 19397), class = "Date"), Value = c(-0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.76, -0.76, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.2, -0.81, -0.2, -0.2, -0.2, -0.0299999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.2, -0.2, -0.5, -0.0299999999999998, -0.57, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, -0.4, -0.79, -0.75, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.35, -0.04, -0.5, -0.5, 
-0.5, -0.5, -0.0299999999999998, -0.02, -0.75, -0.75, -0.75, 
-0.81, -0.81, -0.36, -0.8, -0.0600000000000001, -0.78, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.77, -0.77, -0.0800000000000001, -0.8, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0899999999999999, -0.0899999999999999, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0899999999999999, -0.0899999999999999, 
-0.35, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.8, -0.32, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.4, -0.4, -0.73, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.04, -0.04, -0.7, -0.04, -0.51, -0.65, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0499999999999998, -0.76, -0.76, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.76, -0.76, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.75, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, -0.04, -0.65, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.55, -0.0600000000000001, -0.78, -0.78, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.00999999999999979, -0.0299999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.76, -0.76, -0.75, -0.75, -0.75, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.16, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.77, -0.77, -0.77, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.77, -0.77, -0.77, -0.77, -0.76, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.76, -0.76, -0.75, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0899999999999999, 
-0.0899999999999999, -0.75, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.00999999999999979, -0.8, -0.75, -0.75, -0.75, -0.75, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.75, -0.75, -0.5, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.74, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, -0.04, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.04, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.3, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.17, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, -0.76, -0.76, -0.65, 
-0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.7, 
-0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.6, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, 
-0.7, -0.7, -0.0299999999999998, -0.73, -0.0299999999999998, 
-0.0299999999999998, -0.0299999999999998, -0.0299999999999998, 
-0.74, -0.0800000000000001, -0.73, -0.51, -0.35, -0.35, -0.35, 
-0.84, -0.79, -0.79, -0.79, -0.8, -0.4, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.7, -0.04, -0.75, -0.02, -0.76, -0.0299999999999998, -0.0299999999999998, 
-0.0299999999999998, -0.1, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.42, -0.0899999999999999, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.55, -0.1, -0.0899999999999999, -0.0899999999999999, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.42, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.0699999999999998, -0.42, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.42, -0.42, -0.0699999999999998, -0.02, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, -0.1, -0.0899999999999999, 
-0.1, -0.0800000000000001, -0.55, -0.0899999999999999, -0.65, 
-0.25, -0.65, -0.65, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.77, -0.77, -0.77, -0.77, -0.77, -0.7, -0.17, -0.17, -0.41, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.75, -0.17, -0.7, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.7, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0299999999999998, -0.74, -0.1, -0.1, 
-0.1, -0.0299999999999998, -0.0299999999999998, -0.04, -0.0299999999999998, 
-0.3, -0.4, -0.4, -0.17, -0.72, -0.1, -0.0899999999999999, -0.1, 
-0.1, -0.1, -0.1, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.75, -0.25, -0.74, -0.55, -0.62, -0.75, 
-0.73, -0.0600000000000001, -0.15, -0.78, -0.3, -0.74, -0.54, 
-0.7, -0.0299999999999998, -0.76, -0.0699999999999998, -0.25, 
-0.7, -0.75, -0.11, -0.75, -0.76, -0.4, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0299999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.55, -0.0299999999999998, -0.8, -0.7, 
-0.74, -0.74, -0.4, -0.0499999999999998, -0.75, -0.71, -0.83, 
-0.5, -0.0299999999999998, -0.00999999999999979, -0.00999999999999979, 
-0.00999999999999979, -0.65, -0.0299999999999998, -0.04, -0.04, 
-0.75, -0.04, -0.75, -0.6, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.79, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0299999999999998, -0.00999999999999979, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.71, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0899999999999999, 
-0.04, -0.79, -0.0499999999999998, -0.71, -0.0699999999999998, 
0, -0.75, -0.75, -0.75, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.1, -0.5, -0.5, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.79, 
-0.0299999999999998, -0.0299999999999998, -0.55, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.77, -0.77, -0.75, -0.3, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.55, -0.0600000000000001, -0.55, -0.55, 
-0.55, -0.55, -0.0800000000000001, -0.55, -0.55, -0.73, -0.71, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.02, -0.55, -0.55, -0.55, -0.6, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.55, -0.55, -0.55, -0.55, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0699999999999998, -0.4, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.82, -0.5, -0.0699999999999998, -0.02, -0.1, -0.02, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.35, -0.35, -0.1, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.75, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.75, -0.75, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0699999999999998, -0.0600000000000001, 
-0.0600000000000001, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.0499999999999998, -0.0499999999999998, -0.0800000000000001, 
-0.0800000000000001, -0.0800000000000001, -0.75, -0.75, -0.02, 
-0.18, -0.18, -0.18, -0.18, -0.18, -0.18), Type = c("Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", 
"Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 1", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 2", 
"Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2", "Type 2")), row.names = c(NA, -600L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

I'd like to be able to filter df2, by the contents of df1. I'd like to be able to create a subset that filters only by the Type that appears in df1, as well as the previous day (of the date listed in df1). So df1 has a row for 23/01/2023, I'd like to be able to filter by the previous workday (which would be 20/01/2023).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: (1) Your first dput output starts in the middle, we cannot use it easily. (2) The `internal.selfref=<pointer:0x000...>` in the second structure means that we cannot use your data as-is without editing it. While it's not hard (I'll do it for you in a second, wrapping in `as.data.table` to better represent what you have), it's much appreciated if you make sure data samples are whole and directly-usable. Thanks!

Comment: (But since we don't have your `df1` in a usable state, we can't really test on your code.)

Comment: Very sorry, it's fixed now

Comment: One other point: all of `df2` is from a single date. I suggest you provide a more varied sample of `df2`, and since we really don't need 600 rows, please reduce it to (say) 10-20 rows with various types and dates that match in a `df1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll modify your sample to be more varied and smaller:

```r
df1[, Date := as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y")]
set.seed(42)
df1a <- df1[sample(.N, 10),]
df2a <- df1[sample(.N, 10),][, .(Date = Date + -2:2, Type), by = .(a=1:10)][, Value := runif(50, -1, 0)][, a := NULL]
df1a[1:3,]
#          Date Height   Type
#        <Date> <char> <char>
# 1: 2023-01-30   Long Type 1
# 2: 2022-11-24 Medium Type 2
# 3: 2022-11-28 Medium Type 2
df2a[1:3,]
#          Date   Type       Value
#        <Date> <char>       <num>
# 1: 2022-11-26 Type 1 -0.05333177
# 2: 2022-11-27 Type 1 -0.91756244
# 3: 2022-11-28 Type 1 -0.48578822
```

We can do a non-equi join on them:

```r
df2a[,c("d1","d2") := .(Date-1, Date)]
df1a[df2a, on = .(Type == Type, Date >= d1, Date <= d2), nomatch = 0]
#           Date Height   Type     Date.1     i.Date      Value
#         <Date> <char> <char>     <Date>     <Date>      <num>
#  1: 2023-01-22  Short Type 2 2023-01-23 2023-01-23 -0.2624044
#  2: 2023-01-23  Short Type 2 2023-01-24 2023-01-24 -0.1889449
#  3: 2023-01-22  Short Type 1 2023-01-23 2023-01-23 -0.6204408
#  4: 2023-01-23  Short Type 1 2023-01-24 2023-01-24 -0.5642284
#  5: 2022-11-23 Medium Type 1 2022-11-24 2022-11-24 -0.0424234
#  6: 2022-11-24 Medium Type 1 2022-11-25 2022-11-25 -0.1122451
#  7: 2023-01-29   Long Type 1 2023-01-30 2023-01-30 -0.2512046
#  8: 2023-01-30   Long Type 1 2023-01-31 2023-01-31 -0.3227232
#  9: 2022-11-23 Medium Type 2 2022-11-24 2022-11-24 -0.3243927
# 10: 2022-11-23 Medium Type 2 2022-11-24 2022-11-24 -0.3243927
# 11: 2022-11-24 Medium Type 2 2022-11-25 2022-11-25 -0.0171828
# 12: 2022-11-24 Medium Type 2 2022-11-25 2022-11-25 -0.0171828
# 13: 2023-01-29   Long Type 2 2023-01-30 2023-01-30 -0.9570112
# 14: 2023-01-29   Long Type 2 2023-01-30 2023-01-30 -0.9570112
# 15: 2023-01-29   Long Type 2 2023-01-30 2023-01-30 -0.9570112
# 16: 2023-01-30   Long Type 2 2023-01-31 2023-01-31 -0.8595209
# 17: 2023-01-30   Long Type 2 2023-01-31 2023-01-31 -0.8595209
# 18: 2023-01-30   Long Type 2 2023-01-31 2023-01-31 -0.8595209
```

I added `d1` and `d2` since the join process can be confusing with regards to which `Date` is preserved in a column: during inequality joins, it is not always clear to me.

FYI, in `data.table`-speak, a left-join is symbolically:

```r
RHS[LHS, on = .(join columns), nomatch = 0]
```

So the *second* referenced frame is the LHS, not the first. Counterintuitive perhaps but "this is the way". :-)

There is something going on here that we can't know with just your data, and while it might be an artifact of how I created `df2a`, we aren't guarding against it: this is actually a many-to-many join. Let's add row numbers to each frame and repeat the join:

```r
df1a[, rn := .I]
df2a[, rn := .I]
df1a[df2a, on = .(Type == Type, Date >= d1, Date <= d2), nomatch = 0]
#           Date Height   Type    rn     Date.1     i.Date      Value  i.rn
#         <Date> <char> <char> <int>     <Date>     <Date>      <num> <int>
#  1: 2023-01-22  Short Type 2     6 2023-01-23 2023-01-23 -0.2624044     8
#  2: 2023-01-23  Short Type 2     6 2023-01-24 2023-01-24 -0.1889449     9
#  3: 2023-01-22  Short Type 1     9 2023-01-23 2023-01-23 -0.6204408    18
#  4: 2023-01-23  Short Type 1     9 2023-01-24 2023-01-24 -0.5642284    19
#  5: 2022-11-23 Medium Type 1     5 2022-11-24 2022-11-24 -0.0424234    23
#  6: 2022-11-24 Medium Type 1     5 2022-11-25 2022-11-25 -0.1122451    24
#  7: 2023-01-29   Long Type 1     1 2023-01-30 2023-01-30 -0.2512046    33
#  8: 2023-01-30   Long Type 1     1 2023-01-31 2023-01-31 -0.3227232    34
#  9: 2022-11-23 Medium Type 2     2 2022-11-24 2022-11-24 -0.3243927    38
# 10: 2022-11-23 Medium Type 2    10 2022-11-24 2022-11-24 -0.3243927    38
# 11: 2022-11-24 Medium Type 2     2 2022-11-25 2022-11-25 -0.0171828    39
# 12: 2022-11-24 Medium Type 2    10 2022-11-25 2022-11-25 -0.0171828    39
# 13: 2023-01-29   Long Type 2     4 2023-01-30 2023-01-30 -0.9570112    48
# 14: 2023-01-29   Long Type 2     7 2023-01-30 2023-01-30 -0.9570112    48
# 15: 2023-01-29   Long Type 2     8 2023-01-30 2023-01-30 -0.9570112    48
# 16: 2023-01-30   Long Type 2     4 2023-01-31 2023-01-31 -0.8595209    49
# 17: 2023-01-30   Long Type 2     7 2023-01-31 2023-01-31 -0.8595209    49
# 18: 2023-01-30   Long Type 2     8 2023-01-31 2023-01-31 -0.8595209    49
```

`rn` is from `df2a` (LHS), and `i.rn` is from `df1a` (RHS, more clearly since `df1a` only has 10 rows and `df2a` has 50 to start with). Note that we have many duplicates in both. In my sample data, we could group on `i.rn` and grab the first row, but that *assumes* that all of the `df1a$Height` values match, which I don't know without a lot more context into the data. Regardless of that, even if we reduced `i.rn` to the first row each, we still have duplicates in `rn`, so you would need to determine how to aggregate or filter.